# XML parse returns null for some tags

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I was trying to parse some xml files which are generated by 3ds max and maya. Everything works fine but some values are returned null. For example concider below (collada with .dae extension) xml generated by max or maya ,

```
  <triangles>
   <p>  234 32 4 23 544 35 43 5 435</p>
  </triangles>
  <triangles>
   <p> 43543 45 34 5 12 34 4 36457 6</p>
  </triangles>
  <triangles>
   <p>2345  325 34 543 5 34 534 5 435</p>
  </triangles>
```

Now when I parse using the java code(i'll provide if needed),

The output is:

```
p has 234 32 4 23 544 35 43 5 435
p has 
p has 2345  325 34 543 5 34 534 5 435
```

The second line of output shows nothing even if there is a value. Now, If I edit the line by myself the output is as expected i.e,  the output is shown below Here I have given my own values in the xml file.

The edited xml is

```
 <triangles>
   <p>  234 32 4 23 544 35 43 5 435</p>
  </triangles>
  <triangles>
   <p> 28 234  34 32 4 23 4 23 423  43</p>
  </triangles>
  <triangles>
   <p>2345  325 34 543 5 34 534 5 435</p>
  </triangles>
```

Output is:

```
p has 234 32 4 23 544 35 43 5 435
p has 28 234  34 32 4 23 4 23 423  43
p has 2345  325 34 543 5 34 534 5 435
```

Above I have explained the problem I am facing. [Here](http://purple-works.com/yardstick/tablemaya.dae) you can find the file which is generated by maya. The java code which I have used is given below.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {        

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("d://tablemaya.dae"));

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
                 doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("library_geometries");
            int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);
            Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(0);
            if(firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;

                //-------
                NodeList geometrylist = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("geometry");
                System.out.println(geometrylist.getLength() + " Geometry size");
                for(int k=0;k<geometrylist.getLength();k++) {
                    Element geometryItr = (Element)geometrylist.item(k);

                    NodeList meshlist = geometryItr.getElementsByTagName("mesh");

                    System.out.println("Mesh length is " + meshlist.getLength());


                    for(int k1=0;k1<meshlist.getLength();k1++) {
                        Element geometryItr1 = (Element)meshlist.item(k1);

                        NodeList meshlist1 = geometryItr1.getElementsByTagName("source");

                        System.out.println("Source length is " + meshlist1.getLength());                        
                    }
                    for(int k2=0;k2<meshlist.getLength();k2++) {
                        Element geometryItr1 = (Element)meshlist.item(k2);

                        NodeList trianglelist = geometryItr1.getElementsByTagName("triangles");

                        //System.out.println("Triangles length is " + trianglelist.getLength());     

                            for(int o=0;o<trianglelist.getLength();o++) {

                                Element trichildnodes = (Element) trianglelist.item(o);
                                NodeList inputs = trichildnodes.getElementsByTagName("input");
                            NodeList p = trichildnodes.getElementsByTagName("p");
                            //System.out.println("Fucking Problem " + p.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                            Element ppp = (Element) p.item(0);
                            //System.out.println("Node Value " + ppp.getNodeValue());
                            System.out.println(inputs.getLength() + "Input length");

                            for(int in=0;in<inputs.getLength();in++) {

                                Element inn = (Element) inputs.item(in);
                                System.out.println(inn.getAttribute("semantic") + " " + inn.getAttribute("source") + " Attributes");

                            }

                            for(int i=0; i<p.getLength(); i++) {
                                Element e = (Element)p.item(i);  
                                String ss = e.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                                System.out.println("Noide is " + ss);
                            }
                            //System.out.println(p.getLength() +  " P's length" );
                            //System.out.println("P's content " + ppp.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());


                        }


                    }
                    for(int k1=0;k1<meshlist.getLength();k1++) {
                        Element geometryItr1 = (Element)meshlist.item(k1);

                        NodeList meshlist1 = geometryItr1.getElementsByTagName("vertices");

                        System.out.println("Vertices length is " + meshlist1.getLength());                      
                    }


                }

            }


        }catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am unable to get all the contents of `<p>`. What may be the problem is it with my code or with xml? Please some one help me with this regard. Thank for reading my question.

Vinay

Comment: I'm not able to understand the difference between XML sources. I mean, what **exactly** did you edit by hand? However your code is rather obfuscated. [I made a sample program using XPath](http://pastebin.com/8GqmAebC). Tell me if you are able to reproduce your error with it

Comment: Thanks for the reply Raffaele. I used this code for some reasons and sorry for that. I checked your code it works with the same problem which I had. I have changed the contents of <p> for which I was not getting the values and upon changing it works

Comment: So you inserted random content inside the <p>? How does my code behave with your actual source? Notice that I grab the content from the URL you provided. Does it throw an Exception? What does it print?

Comment: Obviously, on my computer my program works as expected

Comment: I changed the code to get the node values. Its printing the node values for all except the second one. But it shows the index values. Please try to get the values instead of indices and you will see that it doesn't print the values

Comment: If it shows the indices values but does not print it to the console, it's a simple Eclipse (or other IDE) bug. The second <p> contains too many character and doesn't get printed to the console. You can try to output to a file and open it with a text editor other than Eclipse and see that it works. Please, note that if the indices count is non-zero it means that the file content **is successufully read**. This can be true for your code, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be an Eclipse bug. Your code seems correct, and I wrote [my own XPath](http://pastebin.com/8GqmAebC) demo to test the input file. The program runs fine in Eclipse, but when I try to output the `<p>` content via `System.out.println()`, the second `<p>` is not printed to the Eclipse console, because the line has too many characters (more than 30K). See [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=87299#c5) on Eclipse bugzilla:

> I get weird things happening with the console on the Mac, when
>   printing long lines eg:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> {
>     System.out.print("Counting");
>     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
>     for (int i=0; i<28504; i++)
>     {
>         buffer.append("*");
>     }
>     System.out.print(" some more");
>     System.out.println(buffer);
>     System.out.println("Complete");
> }
> ```
>
> The output I get from this is as follows:
>
> ```
> Counting some
> Complete
> ```
>
> ie the long string of '*' isn't displayed and overwrites part of the
>   preceding output
>
> Steve

So the file is successfully read and processed, target information is fully gathered, only the output part is failing, but it's not up to you - and it doesn't affect the program, since I don't think all you want is printing a gigantic line of text to your users' eyes

Comment: I got it. Its not printing because as you said its a very big value. When I output it to a textfile it works. Thanks a lot Raffaele. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Again I have to ask you one question. I stored the values in a list<String> it works when I use substring() to print values. Is it a good way to store or should I use some other datastructure.

Comment: I don't understand where you build your List from, and what it contains. Are you looking for a workaround for the Eclipse's console bug?

Comment: No. The second P node has a large value. I want to store it. I used list to store the P node values. It is saved there. I was just asking you , will it be a good option to use list or should I use any other datastructure as these values are going to be used in the next stage.

Comment: To be clear: **what did you store** in your List? The text content of the P nodes, or the indices? Does your List looks like `List("1 2 3 4", "3 52 34", "3 53 23")` or is it `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` ?

Comment: I stored the values in list.like List("1 2 3 4", "3 52 34", "3 53 23")

Comment: Keeping a big String in memory is never advisable, especially when working with untrusted input. You'll never know what Collada file your program will be feed with, imagine what happens if it's a (pretty common) 20MB file (or a 200MB one!). There's always a tradeoff between flexibility and simplicity. Usually Collada files are meant to be translated to some *proprietary* binary format - which at runtime are faster to load. If it's your case, too, you should throw away your List and using a *piping* style, where the P content is immediately used to generate the output and then is discarded

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I concider piping.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are printing the first node.

```
ppp.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

You could try like this:

```
ppp.getElementsByTagName("p").getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

This should solve the problem. The `getFirstChild` will take the first node inside `ppp`, and this could be an text.

Answer (score 0):

I did not dive in your code completely but this seems to be more of a issue of value bigger than the datatype in which you are trying to hold it.

As 43543 is the biggest value and is being missed.